# DotNnetNuke 6 Changes to css class "dnnFormRequired" So that is appear as red asterisk?

Tags: css, dotnetnuke, skinning

I have developed a custom DNN Module. In doing so I have followed DotNetNuke 6 patterns for consistent user experience (For more information have a look at the following guide)

http://uxguide.dotnetnuke.com/UIPatterns/SimpleFormDemo.aspx

How ever I do not like the way DNN default skin shows the required fields. How can I change the mandatory indication to traditional 
Label: *  Textfield

What changes to the skin (css class) should I make to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will require more than just a change to the CSS, as the overall design pattern does not involve putting any "*" in the content.  So you will need to not only modify the classes, but content as well.  (Unless you go with a JS or other type solution which I don't recommend.)

Answer (score 0):

In your css do something like this to get rid of the red indicator
input.dnnFormRequired{border-left: 0px;}

Then I guess you could do some Javascript to add the * after any dnnFormRequired

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("input.dnnFormRequired").after('*'); 
}); 
</script>
```

Hopefully get you a little further along with what you are trying to achieve.
Even if it does break the UI guidelines ;)

Comment: Many thanks for replying. Is there a way to do using css only. It will be great if I can just make changes to css file (portal skin.css) and it will change the required field look and on all the pages of the portal.

Comment: Not really. You might be able to use CSS to target that element and do a background of an asterisk and pad it with margins and stuff. This is  the simplest / easiest 'hack' of a solution that will work on the most browsers.

Comment: Many Thanks for your answer. This is defiantly one of the solution.